# How to log and audit Azure Functions code and configuration changes

Tags: azure, function, security, logging

How can code and configuration changes to Azure Functions be logged and audited?  I'm trying to create ways to track and guard against malicious insiders making unauthorized changes to the functionality of Azure Functions.  In AWS I can create a CloudTrail trail that logs all write events to Lambda functions and write them to an S3 bucket; the Events are also visible in the Event history section of the CloudTrail console.  However, I can't seem to find a way to do something similar for Azure Functions, especially in Azure Stack.  I've scoured the Activity Log and the Monitor to no avail.  Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Azure has a new feature called Change Analysis
https://aka.ms/changeanalysis

If you are logged in you probably can go directly here
https://portal.azure.com/?feature.customportal=false#blade/Microsoft_Azure_ChangeAnalysis/ChangeAnalysisBladeV2

This feature is also incorporated into the activity log and you can view the changes that were done.  The only issue is it's only for 14 days.  They are working on creating allowing export to Log Analytics so it could go back further.

You can create alerts on the activity log.  The updates you are referring too should trigger an activity log

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/activity-log-alerts

Comment: Thank you!  I tried to use Application Change Analysis and ran into a disappointing side effect.  When I deleted the Azure Function entirely I expected to see the deletion recorded in the Application Change Analysis screen on the Portal.  However, nothing showed up at all because the resource that was being analyzed had been deleted.  So it may be useful to track changes as long as the resource still exists.  And it seems to be a logging and auditing solution, not an alerting solution.

Comment: And alerting on the Activity log works as long as you specify all possible events in the hierarchy to alert on, from the Web site level on down to the Function level.  For example, I put an alert on create, update, and delete on the Function level and then deleted the Web site.  No alert for the Function was triggered even though it was obviously deleted when the Web site was deleted.  Evidently I have to specify alerts at all possible levels to get creates and deletes to be properly alerted.

Comment: You should be able to do that off the activity log for the resource group.  I have viewed deleted change information off the resource group that has shown the delete.  So you could combine the two locations.